# Should we revise thresholds on the celestial mechanics question?

Tags: discussion

On [What celestial mechanics questions are on topic here?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/what-celestial-mechanics-questions-are-on-topic-here) I established some pretty strict thresholds since it is a controversial issue. However, activity has died off and both answers are pretty far short of the threshold of 10 upvotes and score of no less than 5.

I would like to revise the threshold to 5 upvotes and score of no less than 3.

What do you all think?

Comment: At the time of writing this would not have forced one of the answers to be accepted.

Comment: My feeling is that we should keep working on answers to the other question. Your answer is 700 words long and though written very clearly I can't figure out what it actually means, which certainly at least partly my problem but I have a hunch it could be distilled to a few rules that could be easier to grasp by my handful of working brain cells and apply, and the other answer who's author won't respond to queries for clarification. I'm wondering if there are other ways that SE communities have found useful to try to handle scope issues? I can't think of one myself though.

Comment: @uhoh My concern is that even with new, simple answers that people's attention to this issue is already spent and it would be hard to attract enough interest to get sufficient votes. I don't want to force one answer, and I'm happy to make this revision a smidge higher to prevent doing that, but I do firmly believe the threshold needs to be revised.

Comment: @uhoh How does 7 upvotes and a score of 5 sound to you?

Comment: I'm fine with new thresholds either as proposed in the question above or those mentioned in your comments here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We (the mods) spoke amongst ourselves and decided we're going to go ahead and change the threshold to what I mentioned to uhoh in the [comments](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1508/should-we-revise-thresholds-on-the-celestial-mechanics-question?cb=1#comment5641_1508) above. That is, 7 upvotes and score of no less than 5.