# Isn't this question on-topic and shouldn't it be reopened? No need to block answers nor migrate, is there?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question, close-reasons, closed-questions

The question [Can a moon orbit its planet faster than its planet rotates?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/48597/12102) is well received and has had plenty of positivity and several answers.

After reviewing [Community Policy Repository](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1444/12102) and specifically these two items selected from it:

> #### Scope
>
> - [Is planetary science on topic?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/313/58)
> - [Which celestial mechanics questions are on topic?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1494/58)

**Question:** Can any valid reason be found for this question to remain closed **as off-topic** and answers blocked? Or instead, should three more reopen votes be cast?

If not, and *unless migration is imminent* there's no justification for the continued blocking of answer posts.

As far as I know, "better asked on" or "more about" type situations do not automatically make a question *a priori*<sup>1</sup> off-topic

There was a suggestion there that

> This would seem to be a question mostly about astronomy with no real connection to space exploration.

But since we have a *repository of community policies*, let's open it up and see what's inside rather than start from scratch each time with *ad hoc*<sup>2</sup> impressions of what a question seems like.

---

<sup>1</sup>[*a priori*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_priori_and_a_posteriori#A_priori): ...that which is independent from experience. Examples include mathematics, tautologies, and deduction from pure reason.

<sup>2</sup>[*ad hoc*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc): ...generally signifies a solution designed for a specific problem or task, non-generalizable, and not intended to be adapted to other purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be on topic. It's a bit borderline, but would fall under the realm of planetary science and orbital mechanics, both of which are valid subjects here. The same question would also be on topic at Physics, but that shouldn't preclude it from being on topic here as well.

Comment: Sometimes I just happen to be looking in the right spot at the right time:-)

Answer (score 2):

No, this has nothing to do with space exploration, and is just more scope creep.

Being well received and/or receiving answers doesn't make a question on topic.

Regardless, this particular question shows no research effort, so is a poor question anyway.

The accepted answer that forms the community policy no longer meets the criteria stated for acceptance (a score of no less than 5) and hasn't since the end of May. It appears the more "highly regarded" answer (which has met the original criteria, not just the lowered-bar) is being ignored on the basis the other answer was first to reach the criteria. It may be they've not had chance to revise the accepted answer yet.